# Transpose query using SQL query

Tags: sql, json

I am currently having one problem and I need your help. In my data table, I have one column contains all information that I need, but it has json type. Hence, I have to use SQL query to parse these information.

However, those information now becomes several columns, and that's not what I need. So, may I ask if I want to change these information into rows, which mean transpose the table result, what function should I use? Thanks in advance. My table result contains several rows and several columns.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Some databases have parsers natively, others do not.  All that said, sounds like you should parse this in code rather than in sql.  Better yet, dont put json into your database, just fix your schema and insert the data propertly

Comment: MS SQL server has a pivot function that can do this.